# Can Bioinformatics be used in developing a marketable product?

Tags: untagged

As we all know computer science, electrical engineering, etc. knowhows can be used in developing software and electronics/electrical products that can be sold to end-users (B2C).

Can bioinformatics be used to develop such products other than drug discovery?

Or, is it just about scientific/academic research meant for B2B clients?

Comment: This question appears to be asking for opinions, rather than an answer to a specific problem, and as such doesn't fit well with the StackExchange format. I recommend you try elsewhere for an answer, e.g. the [Bioinformatics subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/bioinformatics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pivotal to vaccine research at multiple levels:

1. Deep theoretical vaccine design, which takes years to get to market (my stuff's gone into that and still stuck in advanced clinical trials).
2. Looking for variants that might have evolved immunoevasion against current vaccines involving SARS-CoV-2 (why do we need so many boosters?) and influenza.

Bioinformatic patents are tricky.

The reality is both points are not systematically automated in 'point and click' user friendliness. Its definitely of commercial value at an industrial/institutional level. However most work is submitted to the public domain and code freely available or held under a commercial firewall.

Generally, I think you underestimate how much bioinformatic work takes place in modern clinical practice and when fighting a virus how it just keeps evolving around all the obstacles thrown at it.

More generally, a lot of bioinformatics is used to direct wet-lab research because bioinformatics gets to the answers quicker.